How to find Riemann invariants of a system
I'm trying to find the Riemann invariants of the system
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t} +( \alpha +V)\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x} -\alpha \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} =0\\
\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} +V\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x} =0
\end{array}
But I don't understand what to do with the characteristic matrix
\begin{array}
\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha +V & -\alpha \\
V & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{array}
The eigenvalues of this matrix are $\displaystyle \lambda _{1} =\alpha ,\ \lambda _{2} =\ V$, eigenvectors
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\alpha }{V}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
I got the following invariants:
\begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\frac{\alpha }{V} d\alpha +dV=0,\ \\
d\left( \alpha ^{2} +V^{2}\right) =0,\\
I_{1} =\ \alpha ^{2} +V^{2} .\\
\\
d\alpha +dV=0,\\
d( \alpha +V) =0,\\
I_{2} \ =\ \alpha +V.
\end{array}
In new coordinates I have the following system of equations: \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\alpha \frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t} +V\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} +\alpha ^{2}\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x} +\alpha V\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} =0\\
\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t} +\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} +V\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x} +V\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} =0.
\end{array}
If I go to the original coordinates, then after the transformations I get the system:
\begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t} +( \alpha +V)\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x} +V\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} =0\\
\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} V-\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \alpha =0.
\end{array}
It is different from the original one.
$\displaystyle -\alpha \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$  instead of $\displaystyle V\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$
and
$\displaystyle V\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \alpha $ instead of$\displaystyle -\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \alpha $.
Can you tell me what I did wrong?
As I understand it, the problem occurs due to the components
$-\alpha \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$ and $V\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial x}.$ But how to solve it?
upd:I realized the mistake. I found right eigenvectors instead of left ones.

There is a wikipedia page on the topic. Else Whithams 'Linear and Nonlinear Waves' is a good read for this topic. You could also probably use this problem as an example.

@MatthewCassell
Thank you! These are really good links

I also answered a question from Whithams book on the topic above the other day. I was going to omit it but it ties in with the other two links in my previous comment so it might also be of some use to you.

@MatthewCassell Thank you for the link. I tried following the example. But when I replace it back, I get the wrong system. Could you please see where I went wrong?

If I recall my working from when I did the question above, I got that the eigenvalues are $a$ and $v$ with corresponding eigenvectors are $(-1, 1)$ and $(-v, a)$ respectively (though don't quote me on this). In turn, the gradient of the Riemann invariants $(\partial_{a} R, \partial_{v} R)$ are orthogonal to the eigenvectors which yields $(\partial_{a} R, \partial_{v} R) = (1, 1) \implies R = s (a, v)$ for the first and eigenvector and $R = s (a^{2}, v^{2})$ for the second, $s \in \mathbb{R}$. But I will need to check this tonight.

I realized the mistake. I found right eigenvectors instead of left ones. Now it worked. Thank you

Perhaps you might like to answer your own question then, both for completeness so the question isn't flagged as open in the future and so other people that have similar questions have a solution. People might also give you reputation for it too.
